# How to best reorder 100k database rows every hour?

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql - i want to reorder a 100k row database every hour. I have a field called 'order' that i sort by. how can i best reorder it?

I currently do this (pseudo):

```
mainpage.php : select * from table order by `order` desc limit 100;
```

and hourly:

```
cronjob.php  : select * from table order by rand(); 
$i=0;
foreach($row) {
$i++;
update table set order = $i where id = $row['id']
}
```

but it takes ages.

If i just do 'update table set order = rand()' there will be duplicates and i don't want `order` to have duplicates (but it isn't set to a UNIQUE index because as it is updating there will be duplicates.

whats the best way to go about doing this?

(i do it this way because just doing "select * from table order by rand() limit 100" was really slow, but having it on an index is much faster. it just takes quite a while to reorder it)

(mysql 5)

Comment: one question:....WHY?!?!?

Comment: Don't do this in PHP, do it directly on the database (if you have to do it at all).... if you have to do it in PHP, don't loop through each individual record updating it; write an update that does them all in one go

Comment: this is almost certainly something you don't want to do in the first place.  ordering is the job of the SELECT statement, not the INSERT statememt.

Comment: Actually, this _is_ both the job of the `SELECT` and the `INSERT` statement (and an index on column `order`). I agree, though, you certainly don't want to do this manual sorting, just use an index, that's what they're for.

Comment: Why do you care about duplicates generated by a `update table set order = rand()`? It will still be *exactly* as random as having no duplicates. You're shooting yourself in the foot pretty hard here. If you want to guarantee that the duplicates always come out in the same order, simply use `select * form table order by "order", "id"`.

Comment: Yeah the orderby field has an index. that is why i do it. i just want a way to quickly be able to say every hour : Give me a new order of the whole database , so it looks like it is updating

Comment: to clarify, the 100k rows don't change. i just need to quickly be able to display them in a new order every hour. the fastest way is to have a field (that is indexed properly) and then use the ORDER BY on that field. i don't get why you lot are getting so confused. it IS on an index, and isn't anything to do with sequential on disk storage.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an auto increment field and then generate a list of random values (between the min and max stored) to use when selecting?

Comment: because I need to show all 100k eventually (i've made the example a lot more simple than what it really is)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL isn't a sequential-on-disk storage anyway. This doesn't get you anything. Doing this might make rows show up in your management client in a certain order, but it won't actually add any speed to anything. Please just add an `ORDER BY` clause to your select statement.

Comment: I want them to randomly show up, but must change the order every hour so it looks like the site updates. I use a field with an index and sort by that index cos its much faster than anything else i came up with

Comment: So add just set your `ORDER` column to `RAND()` You can have a job that updates this column at some interval. Just please don't actually reorder the table rows. That won't do anything.

Comment: I don't reorder the actual table rows. i set the `order` column to a random number (hourly), then i can just do a select * from table order by `order` - the `order` field is indexed so its faster than just order by rand() on every request

Answer (score 0):

how about creating another table - my_wierd_sort_table.

then delete it entirely, and insert the PK and your rand() column - and use that to order by in your selects...